# LINQ query on PropertyInfo list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a sub class which is 'derived' (is that the right word) from a base class two levels up. I have a list of all the properties in this class (so that includes properties from the parent, and the parent of the parent). What I want is just the properties where the DeclaringType is "CrazyNinjaBadger" (i.e. only the properties from my sub - class).

I've tried this statement:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties().Select(x => x.DeclaringType.ToString() == "CrazyNinjaBadger");
```

But I just get

> "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[]'.

Please can someone suggest a statement that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties().Select(x => x.DeclaringType.ToString() == "CrazyNinjaBadger");
```

`Select(...)` returns an implemenetation of `IEnumerable<T>`. The compiler error is very explicit.

Another point is you want to filter properties. `.Select(...)` is for projecting an enumerable into another of the same or other type.

For example:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = new string[] { "0", "1" };

// Converting the string enumerable to an enumerable of integers:
IEnumerable<int> integers = strings.Select(some => int.Parse(some)); 

// Also, convert each strings into an anonymous object!
IEnumerable<object> whoKnows = strings.Select(some => new { Value = some });
```

In order to filter an enumerable **you need to use `.Where(...)`**.

In the other hand, `x.DeclaringType.ToString() == "CrazyNinjaBadger"` is correct but it should be `x.DeclaringType.Name == "CrazyNinjaBadger"` (you don't need to convert the type to string as `Type` has a property `Name`).

Finally I'd argue that you don't need to set the result in an array, you can just do this:

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = 
       type.GetProperties()
          .Where(x => x.DeclaringType.Name == "CrazyNinjaBadger");
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail... I guess the accepted answer goes to you :)

Comment: @markp3rry Thanks, but check my update! You had another problem: you should use `Where(...)` instead of `Select(...)`!!!

Answer (score 3):

Use `Where` to filter properties, and convert result to array:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties()
             .Where(x => x.DeclaringType.ToString() == "CrazyNinjaBadger")
             .ToArray();
```

Also I believe you want to use type name like this `x.DeclaringType.Name == "CrazyNinjaBadger"`. Btw `Select` operator projects properties to sequence of boolean values in your case. So, your query actually returns `IEnumerable<bool>` with results of type string comparison to CrazyNinjaBadger.

Answer (score 1):

Add `ToArray()` at the end of the line

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties()
    .Select(x => x.DeclaringType.ToString() == "CrazyNinjaBadger")
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because `Select()` always returns an IEnumerable.

Just Add `.ToArray()` at the end of the line to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties()
                   .Select(x => x.DeclaringType.ToString() == "CrazyNinjaBadger")
                   .ToArray();
```

The ToArray() needs to be added to convert to Array...

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there!  Select returns an IEnumerable, but you're trying to set the value of a PropertyInfo array.  All you need is an additional call to ToArray and you're there!

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties().Select(x => x.DeclaringType.ToString() == "CrazyNinjaBadger").ToArray()
```